# How to pass string as context in tapestry 5.3.2 on click of submit

Tags: java, submit, tapestry

I am not able to pass context as string to my submit event handler in Tapestry while submitting form. How it's done?

Comment: What's the component you are using to submit the form ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, provide us more information : code, logs, ...

Comment: I am using tapestry submit which is located outside form.Is it possible to still submit it because i cant put it outside.Submit is not working with an exception i.e no object of type FormSupport is available for the environment

Answer (score 1):

The exception you are seeing is saying that you are not allowed to place the `Submit` outside a tapestry `Form`. A good way to deal with context on a form submit is to add the context to the Form and pick it up on the prepare for submit event. Like so:

```
@Component(id = "form", parameters = {"context=myString"})
private Form form

@OnEvent(component="form", value=EventConstants.PREPARE_FOR_SUBMIT)
private void handlePrepare(String contextString) {
  .... do what is needed with the contextString ...
}

@OnEvent(component="form", value=EventConstants.SUCCESS)
private Object handlePrepare() {
  .... handle form succes ...
  return null;
}

public String getMyString() {
  return "Some string"
}
```

Here you can leave the submit button out of the equation. If you do require the submit button, please provide your java code and *.tml markup in the initial question.

Good luck!